# Lost password requested in root prompt

Tags: lubuntu, password

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) procedure to reset the lost `sudo` password from the root prompt. Unfortunately, a password is requested to access the root prompt. 
Am I missing some obvious step or is it not the right procedure? I am running Lubuntu on a Virtual Machine (W10 Host).

[image]

Comment: Did you set a root password? Or you are talking about the `sudo` password? BTW, you can simply press Ctrl+D as said there...

Comment: Ctrl + D brings back to the menu. I did not set a root password. I am trying to recover the sudo one. Thank you for pointing pointing it out, I was not aware they were different.

Comment: If you get that prompt, then AFAIK you (or someone else with access to the computer) must have set a password for `root` (i.e. enabled the root account). You can either chroot from a live CD/DVD/USB or follow the additional steps here [Can't reset password](http://askubuntu.com/a/804127/178692)

Comment: @muru thanks for the indication, I am checking it right now.

Comment: Since it is a duplicate, should I delete it?

Comment: @Worice No. Others may visit this post and see that it was answered by another post. This will basically act as a redirection page for people having a similar issue :)

Comment: @OwenHines, thanks for the explanation and thanks everybody for your time!